# How do you allow GADTs in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, gadt

Today I started to learn about GADTs from: [haskell.org](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.6.1/docs/html/users_guide/gadt.html) and [https://wiki.haskell.org](https://wiki.haskell.org/GADTs_for_dummies)

Unfortunately, I don't know how to use them. If I run the code from the example I get the following error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

AFP_229.hs:31:1:
Illegal generalised algebraic data declaration for `Term'
  (Use GADTs to allow GADTs)
In the data declaration for `Term'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

This is the code I am using:

```
data Term a where
  Lit    :: Int -> Term Int
  Succ   :: Term Int -> Term Int
  IsZero :: Term Int -> Term Bool   
  If     :: Term Bool -> Term a -> Term a -> Term a
  Pair   :: Term a -> Term b -> Term (a,b)
```

I have tried other sample code, but this gives me the same error. How do you allow GADTs?

Comment: Use a compiler option or a pragma.

https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/ghc-language-features.html#options-language

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `Use GADTS to allow GADTS` looks wild :)

Basically there are two ways to enable language extensions:

- path a `-X<extensions>` to `ghc`, e.g. `ghc -XGADTS`
- put `{-# LANGUAGE <extension> #-}` at the top of a file, e.g. `{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}`

Initially the error messages looked like that: `Use -XGADTs to allow GADTs`, but actually language pragma (the second way) is more common, and people started complaining that it is hard to copy-n-paste extension name from the error message, so `-X` was dropped.

Comment: The `{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}` approach is pretty much always the way to go, because it lets people reading the source see immediately what extensions are in play.

Comment: @dfeuer I agree. Actually that is why it is more common.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is also the option of `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XGADTs #-}`, but that's less readable, so I'd go with a `LANUGAGE` pragma by default, too.